# How to display RSS entry from table view cell in a web view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, rss

I am using iOS 5 & Storyboard.I am able to display the RSS feeds from "http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/INcricketNews" in a tableView.However i am not able to display an entry from a particular cell , when tapped in a webView.Below is my code.

```
@interface BlogRss : NSObject          //This is what i am fetching.

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * description;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * linkUrl;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * guidUrl;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate * pubDate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * mediaUrl;

@end
```

My TableViewController is configured as -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
    if(nil == cell){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
}
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]title];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]description];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"])
{
     ArticleDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   // self.entry = [self.allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
   detailViewController.entry = [self.allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSLog(@"current row contains  %@ ",detailViewController.entry);  //This shows null.

   }

}
```

And this is my WebViewController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.newsView.delegate =self;
  //  self.entry =[[BlogRss alloc]init];
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:self.entry.linkUrl];
    [self.newsView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    NSLog(@"The URL is %@",url);  //This shows null as well.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewWillAppear in the WebViewController, your are allocating a new instance of BlogRss class. Hence overriding the entry assigned during the prepareForSegue.

Try to remove the following line:

```
self.entry =[[BlogRss alloc]init];
```

Another mistake you made is assigning the blog entry in prepareForSegue to self.entry which is referring to the table view controller, not detail view controller.

So update this line in prepareForSegue:

```
self.entry = [self.allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Into:

```
detailViewController.entry = [self.allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but...Still getting the same result... :-)

Comment: @sushrut put some breakpoints and log the self.allEntries objectAtIndex method call whether it is returning the correct object

Comment: Well if i do the NSLog in my BlogRSSParser class,I do get the response.But when i do the NSLog in my TableViewController or WebViewController like above , it shows null..